# parsing a DOMNodeList in PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

A web service return Xml of format

```
<string>
  <NewDataSet>
    <DealBlotter>
      <CustomerReference>161403239</CustomerReference>
      <Symbol>EUR/USD</Symbol>
      <BuySell>S</BuySell>
      <ContractValue>-100000</ContractValue>
      <Price>1.35070</Price>
      <CounterValue>-135070</CounterValue>
      <TradeDate>2011-01-20 22:05:21.690</TradeDate>
      <ConfirmationNumber>78967117</ConfirmationNumber>
      <Status>C</Status>
      <lTID>111913820</lTID>
    </DealBlotter>
  </NewDataSet>
</string>
```

Now i am using curl to access this and then -

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$dom = new DOMDOcument();

// Load your XML as a string
$dom->loadXML($xml);

// Create new XPath object
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$res = $xpath->query("/NewDataSet/DealBlotter");

foreach($res as $node)
{
    print "i went inside foreach";
    $custref =  ($node->getElementsByTagName("CustomerReference")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    print $custref;
    $ccy = ($node->getElementsByTagName("Symbol")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    print $ccy;
    $type = ($node->getElementsByTagName("BuySell")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    $lots = ($node->getElementsByTagName("ContractValue")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    $price = ($node->getElementsByTagName("Price")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    $confnumber = ($node->getElementsByTagName("ConfirmationNumber")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    $status = ($node->getElementsByTagName("Status")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    $ltid = ($node->getElementsByTagName("lTID")->item(0)->nodeValue);
    $time = ($node->getElementsByTagName("TradeDate")->item(0)->nodeValue);

}
```

**But nothing is getting printed.** except the dummy statement.
using `$res = $xpath->query("/string/NewDataSet/DealBlotter");` did not help. Also a `print_r($res);` gives output as `DOMNodeList obect.`

Doing this also does not print anything

```
$objDOM = new DOMDocument(); 
$objDOM->load($result);
$note = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("DealBlotter");
foreach( $note as $value )
{       
    print "hello";  
    $tasks = $value->getElementsByTagName("Symbol");
    $task  = (string)$tasks->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $details = $value->getElementsByTagName("Status");
    $detail  = (string)$details->item(0)->nodeValue;

    print "$task :: $detail <br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `simplexml` and `DOMDocument` you can load the XML using `DOMDocument` on its own?

Comment: Why are all those assignments in brackets?

Comment: your xml data heading tag is missing <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems.

With how you're loading the xml.  Get rid of the `simplexml` line.  It's not needed, and is messing things up.  Instead just do `$dom->loadXml($result);`.  There's no reason to load SimpleXML first if you're going to pass it directly into DomDocument.

With your query, the `/` operator is the direct decendent operator.  So it means directly next to.  So your first tag should be the root.  So either add the root onto it:

```
$res = $xpath->query("/string/NewDataSet/DealBlotter");
```

Or make the leading slash into `//` which selects any matching decendent:

```
$res = $xpath->query("//NewDataSet/DealBlotter");
```

And finally, doing a `var_dump` on `$res` isn't going to tell you much.  Instead, I like to do `var_dump($res->length)` since it'll tell you how many matches it has rather than that it's a domnodelist (which you already know)...

Comment: i did use /string/NewDataSet/DealBlotter. see my full question.

Comment: @ayush: I did see that.  But it's still a contributing problem since it's still in the code.  And did you see the first problem I listed?  Did you try that?  And are you 100% sure `$result` is the xml that you posted?  no differences at all?

Comment: yes the xml is same . i also did $res = $xpath->query("//NewDataSet");
 print_r($res); 
 print_r($res->length); and this got printed: DOMNodeList Object ( ) 1

Comment: So, try running this: `foreach ($res->item(0)->childNodes as $node) { var_dump($node->nodeName); }`  You should see a `DealBlotter` in there.  If not, I question the structure of the xml that you're getting back...